# I am trying to add items in cart in vue js but not sure how to transfer thoes data between components, I have an array with has items information

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component, shopping-cart

I have read many question and articles suggesting to use me emit,props but I am not able to figure it out. Below is my code.
I have an array of products which contains details of product and I want to add those items to cart component with their quantity and display products name in cart.

**Container.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="container pb-130">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <product></product>
      <cartData></cartData>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import product from "@/components/product.vue";
import cartData from "../components/cartData.vue";
export default {
  name: "Container",
  components: {
    product,
    cartData,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.pb-130 {
  padding-bottom: 130px;
}
</style>
```

**product.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" class="product-item">
    <img :src="product.img" alt="Product image" />
    <div class="product-content">
      <div class="product-head">
        <h6 class="product-title">{{ product.name }}</h6>
        <span
          >By<span class="owner">{{ product.owner }}</span></span
        >
      </div>
      <div class="product-footer">
        <div class="price">
          <span>Price</span>
          <span class="val">{{ product.val }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="btns">
          <button
            class="remove-tocart"
            @click="
              updateCart(product, 'subtract');
              removeFromCart(product);
            "
          >
            -
          </button>
          <span class="quantity">{{ product.quantity }}</span>
          <button
            class="add-tocart"
            @click="
              updateCart(product, 'add');
              addToCart(product);
              takeToCart(product);
            "
          >
            +
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "One Tribe Black Edition",
          img: "https://enftymart.themenio.com/img/nft-lg.8f26d1a6.jpg",
          val: "14.99",
          owner: "ZeniconStudio",
          quantity: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "One Tribe Black Edition",
          img: "https://miro.medium.com/max/2000/1*AJrLFnuCAD8dE1p1Bg0dbg.jpeg",
          val: "15.99",
          owner: "ZeniconStudio",
          quantity: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "One Tribe Black Edition",
          img: "https://creativereview.imgix.net/content/uploads/2021/09/F4E079D612B9653BEFC4D8D2F39781E39A3025C693B177A61D6C73A5156248EA.jpg?auto=compress,format&q=60&w=1200&h=849",
          val: "14.99",
          owner: "ZeniconStudio",
          quantity: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "One Tribe Black Edition",
          img: "https://coffeebros.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/astronaut-background.jpg",
          val: "14.99",
          owner: "ZeniconStudio",
          quantity: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "One Tribe Black Edition",
          img: "https://cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublishing.com/coindesk/5NOWWNNEBRER7BXFZKCYRCA7NA.jpg",
          val: "14.99",
          owner: "ZeniconStudio",
          quantity: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "One Tribe Black Edition",
          img: "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2021/08/15/fashion/TEEN-NFTS--fewocious/TEEN-NFTS--fewocious-videoSixteenByNineJumbo1600.jpg",
          val: "14.99",
          owner: "ZeniconStudio",
          quantity: 0,
        },
      ],
      cartItems: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateCart(product, updateType) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
        if (this.products[i].id === product.id) {
          if (updateType === "subtract") {
            if (this.products[i].quantity !== 0) {
              this.products[i].quantity--;
            }
          } else {
            this.products[i].quantity++;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    },
    addToCart(product) {
      this.cartItems.push(product);
    },
    removeFromCart(product) {
      this.cartItems.splice(this.cartItems.indexOf(product), 1);
    },
    takeToCart(product) {
      this.$emit("receiveInCart", product);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.product-item {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgb(24 24 24 / 7%);
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 3 - 60px);
}
.product-item {
  margin: 0 15px 15px;
}
.product-item img {
  height: 245px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.product-item .product-content {
  padding: 15px;
}
.product-item .product-content .product-head {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: initial;
}
.product-item .product-content .product-title {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.product-item .product-content .product-head span,
.product-item .product-content .product-footer .price {
  color: #c5c5c5;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.product-item .product-content .product-head .owner,
.product-item .product-content .product-footer .val {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.product-item .product-content .product-footer .val {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}
.product-item .product-content .product-footer .val::before {
  content: "$";
}
.product-item .product-content .product-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.product-item .product-content .product-footer .price {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.add-tocart,
.remove-tocart {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1.5px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.add-tocart:hover,
.remove-tocart:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btns {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 80px;
}
</style>
```

Here is the component where I need data of added item in cart.

**cartData.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="cartData" @receiveInCart="storeData">
    <h1>Your cart</h1>
    <span class="title">{{ item.name }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cartData: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    storeData(data) {
      this.cartData = data;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.cartData {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin: 0 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgb(24 24 24 / 7%);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) and dispatch `action` in `product` component for changing cart data, and with `getter` display cart data in `cartData` component. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-cart-demo-k7dos?file=/src/App.vue) is codesandbox with simple solution.

Comment: Can we do this without vuex?

Comment: hey mate, you can also pass events around instead of vuex, but if your app go bigger it will be hard to maintain it, so for me vuex is better solution

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: You are welcome mate, cheers :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to just add comments on you code as I don't know how to use vuex.

Comment: i will try later, for now I cleaned example and added some more functionality, pls take a look again :)

Comment: Hii can we give the user a feature to increase or decrease the quantities in cart as well, or How can I do that in your code??